# Multiple select boxes but only allow one selection between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning, this one is a bit odd but I was wondering if there was a way to have multiple select boxes but you can only select an item in one.  Example:  I have two select boxes (`breakfast`, `lunch`).

In these select boxes are different options.

**Breakfast** has

- Eggs
- Bacon
- Bagel
- etc.

**Lunch** has:

- Sandwich
- Pizza
- Taco
- etc.

Lets say the user selected `Eggs` in `Breakfast`.  if the user selects `Pizza` in `lunch` then the `Eggs` in `breakfast` is unselected and now `Pizza` in `Lunch` is the selected option.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the underlying logic. Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: How are Eggs and Pizza related to each other? What is it about Eggs for breakfast that means the user can't then have Pizza for lunch? Or are they just not allowed breakfast *and* lunch?

Comment: yes there is a way with JS, but why dont you just use one select box? with maybe `<optgroup label="Breakfast">`

Comment: The user can either have Breakfast OR Lunch not both.  I want to keep the select boxes separate.

Comment: Off-topic, but from a `UX` perspective surely checkboxes/radio buttons would be better in terms of usability, so people know what's available before hand, without clicking on a select dropdown?

Comment: Thanks for updating my question to look more sensible Nick R.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6R58k/

```
$("form").find("select").change(function(){
    $(this).siblings("select").val("");
    // optionally $("form").find("select").not($(this)).val("");        
});
```

Comment: This is awesome!  With select boxes is there a way to just have it not select anything instead of selection the empty option?  I ask because I didn't want to add an empty option.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Or you can go alternate route posted, and go with optgroups.

Comment: this IS selecting nothing...the key here is the val("") part.  That's the part that you need.  Personally I wouldn't use this exact way because the selector used limits these to being siblings.  I'd use ID's or a class to relate them.

Comment: TwiStar nice additional selector provided.  Well done sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Breakfast">
        <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
        <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Lunch">
        <option value="Sandwich">Sandwich</option>
        <option value="Pizza">Pizza</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: They have to be two separate select boxes

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/FnXPy/

```
$(function($){
    $(".meal").on("change", function() {
        var me = $(this);
        $(".meal").each(function() {
            if(me.attr("id") != $(this).attr("id")) {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

A variation using classes instead of DOM structure to find the related selects.

Comment: You can use `this.id` and `this.value` instead of jQuery wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

ok you can use

```
<form class="form" action="#">
  Breakfast has : <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Breakfast" value="Eggs"> Eggs<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Breakfast" value="Bacon"> Bacon<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Breakfast" value="Bagel"> Bagel<br>
  Lunch has:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Lunch" value="Sandwich"> Sandwich<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Lunch" value="Pizza"> Pizza<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Lunch" value="Taco"> Taco<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and then:

```
$(".form:checked") //do anything ;
```

Comment: Radio buttons would make a lot more sense than checkboxes, assuming users can only choose one.